# Continuous referencing of subfigures

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

Yes, I know it is deprecated, but I am for now stuck with using the `subfigure` package for my document. I added the following lines to have continuous numbering in my figures and tables:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{subsection}
```

However, this only partly works, as I can correctly reference the main label. For example:

```
\begin{figure}[!hpbt]
\centering
\subfigure[SUBDESCRIPTION1]
{
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE1}
    \label{fig:SUBLABEL1}
}
\qquad
\subfigure[SUBDESCRIPTION2]
{
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE2}
    \label{fig:SUBLABEL2}
}
\caption[screen]{MAINDESCRIPTION}
\label{fig:MAINLABEL}
\end{figure}
```

Using

```
(e.g. Figure~\ref{fig:MAINLABEL})
```

correctly shows up in the text as the sequential number (e.g. "Figure 4"). Also, using

```
(e.g. Subfigure~\subref{fig:SUBLABEL2})
```

correctly shows up as (e.g. Subfigure (b)).

However, when I use

```
blabla, Figure~\ref{fig:SUBLABEL2}, ...
```

it instead shows up as: blabla, Figure 3.4 (b), ...

where 3 is the chapter number.

So my question is, how do I get rid of the chapter and the dot and so that I just have:
blabla, Figure 4 (b), ...  ?

Comment: Would working with the `subfig` package instead of the `subfigure` package be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the package `subfigure` after the modification with `\counterwithout`:

```
\documentclass[demo]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{subsection}
\usepackage[]{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}[!hpbt]
\centering
\subfigure[SUBDESCRIPTION1]
{
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE1}
    \label{fig:SUBLABEL1}
}
\qquad
\subfigure[SUBDESCRIPTION2]
{
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE2}
    \label{fig:SUBLABEL2}
}
\caption[screen]{MAINDESCRIPTION}
\label{fig:MAINLABEL}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

Using

(e.g. Figure~\ref{fig:MAINLABEL})
correctly shows up in the text as the sequential number (e.g. "Figure 4"). Also, using

(e.g. Subfigure~\subref{fig:SUBLABEL2})
correctly shows up as (e.g. Subfigure (b)).

However, when I use

blabla, Figure~\ref{fig:SUBLABEL2}, ...
it instead shows up as: blabla, Figure 3.4 (b), ...

where 3 is the chapter number.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Marco. Happy to see you! Didn't even think to deal with `subfigure` since it is years I don't use it. +1.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Of course your solution is the correct recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

May this be one of the reasons why `subfigure` is deprecated?

Using `subcaption` it doesn't happen...

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithout{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\counterwithout{table}{subsection}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{figure}[!hpbt]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE1}
    \caption{SUBDESCRIPTION1}\label{fig:SUBLABEL1}
\end{subfigure}
\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=8cm]{images/GRAPHICFILE2}
    \caption{SUBDESCRIPTION2}\label{fig:SUBLABEL2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MAINDESCRIPTION}
\label{fig:MAINLABEL}
\end{figure}

e.g. Figure~\ref{fig:MAINLABEL}

e.g. Subfigure~\subref{fig:SUBLABEL2}

blabla, Figure~\ref{fig:SUBLABEL2}, ...

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I know it works with `subcaption`. But as I said, for now I'm stuck on the `subfigure` package. :(

Comment: @Markstar Happy that Marco has solved your problem. Anyway, as soon as possible, switch to `subcaption` :-)

Comment: Yes, I will. :-) Thank you again for your help!